# Get Hibernate SessionFactory from JPA's entityManagerFactory

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need a specific feature of hibernate that is StatelessSession and for that I need Hibernate's SessionFactory. The problem is I only have the entityManagerFactory. How can I get a StatelessSession in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by injecting it, defining the bean like this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup

Answer (score 50):

**Option 1 through `EntityManagerFactory`**

If you use `Hibernate >= 4.3` and `JPA 2.1` you can accces the `SessionFactory` from a `EntityManagerFactory` through `<T> T EntityManagarFactory#unwrap(Class<T> cls)`.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

---

**Option 2 through `EntityManager`**

If you use `Hibernate >= 4.3` and `JPA >= 2.0` then you can accces the `Session` from the `EntityManager` through `<T> T EntityManagar#unwrap(Class<T> cls)`. From the `Session` you can obtain the `SessionFactory`.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
```

Comment: vice versa is possible ? I have the SessionFactory object but for some reason I need EntityManagar

Comment: @dom no it’s not possible.

Answer (score 10):

Try to cast `EntityManagerFactory` to [`HibernateEntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/HibernateEntityManagerFactory.html).

Since `EntityManagerFactory` doesn't support `unwrap()` (unlike `EntityManager`), it seems to be the only way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Worked fine for me: HibernateEntityManagerFactory emFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) em.getEntityManagerFactory();

Comment: Since JPA 2.1 `EntityManageFactory` now provides an `unwrap()` method.

Answer (score 7):

Hibernate >= 4.3 supports JPA 2.1. So you can use EntityManagerFactory.unwrap like emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) there.

Comment: Another solution is to unwrap the EntityManager into a Session and then get the SessionManager from the session. This also works in jpa 2.0