# Can't inject Hibernate SessionFactory in ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, blob

I am building a SpringBoot application and I am trying to programatically populate my test database.

I came up with this:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Component
public class DatabaseFillerOnStartup implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Resource
private SomeRepository someRepository;

@Resource //This doesn't work
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    ...
```

One of my entities has a Blob where I want to save an image:

```
   private Blob createBlobWithSampleImage() {
    InputStream imageStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample1.jpg");
    LobCreator lobCreator = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
    try {
        return lobCreator.createBlob(IOUtils.toByteArray(imageStream));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't manage to inject the sessionFactory.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Thanks to riversidetraveler answer I managed to find this other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667910/no-currentsessioncontext-configured that helped too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing where you've configured your session factory.  Are you using  [spring-boot-starter-data-jpa](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) or are you wiring up the SessionFactory yourself in an @Configuration annotated class or via standard xml bean config?

Edit:
Based on that answer check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030022/get-hibernate-sessionfactory-from-jpas-entitymanagerfactory).

Comment: I am using  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. This is really my first project from scratch so some things are just working by themselves and I don't really know howyet.